# date intervals in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of dates in a data frame that are represented as strings. I want to create a column representing the dates as intervals. My data looks like this

```
df1=DataFrame({'x1':[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,7,9,10,5,3,2,7,3,8,4,3,7,2,5,5,2,2],'date':['2014-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-02','2014-01-02','2014-01-03','2014-01-04','2014-01-05','2014-01-05','2014-01-05','2014-01-05','2014-01-06','2014-01-07','2014-01-07','2014-01-08','2014-01-09','2014-01-10','2014-01-10','2014-01-10','2014-01-10','2014-01-11','2014-01-12','2014-01-12']})


          date  x1
0   2014-01-01   1
1   2014-01-01   5
2   2014-01-01   2
3   2014-01-01   6
4   2014-01-02   3
5   2014-01-02   7
6   2014-01-03   4
7   2014-01-04   7
8   2014-01-05   9
9   2014-01-05  10
10  2014-01-05   5
11  2014-01-05   3
12  2014-01-06   2
13  2014-01-07   7
14  2014-01-07   3
15  2014-01-08   8
16  2014-01-09   4
17  2014-01-10   3
18  2014-01-10   7
19  2014-01-10   2
20  2014-01-10   5
21  2014-01-11   5
22  2014-01-12   2
23  2014-01-12   2
```

but I want it to look like this

```
 df['level']=['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c']

          date  x1 level
 0   2014-01-01   1     a
 1   2014-01-01   5     a
 2   2014-01-01   2     a
 3   2014-01-01   6     a
 4   2014-01-02   3     a
 5   2014-01-02   7     a
 6   2014-01-03   4     a
 7   2014-01-04   7     a
 8   2014-01-05   9     b
 9   2014-01-05  10     b
 10  2014-01-05   5     b
 11  2014-01-05   3     b
 12  2014-01-06   2     b
 13  2014-01-07   7     b
 14  2014-01-07   3     b
 15  2014-01-08   8     b
 16  2014-01-09   4     c
 17  2014-01-10   3     c
 18  2014-01-10   7     c
 19  2014-01-10   2     c
 20  2014-01-10   5     c
 21  2014-01-11   5     c
 22  2014-01-12   2     c
 23  2014-01-12   2     c
```

Where a represents the time interval ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-04], b represents ['2014-01-05, '2014-01-08'], and c represents ['2014-01-09', '2014-01-12']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map using the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect

dates = ['2014-01-04', '2014-01-08', '2014-01-12']
df1['level'] = df1.date.apply(lambda d: chr(ord('a') + bisect.bisect_left(dates, d)))
>> df1
          date  x1 level
0   2014-01-01   1     a
1   2014-01-01   5     a
2   2014-01-01   2     a
3   2014-01-01   6     a
4   2014-01-02   3     a
5   2014-01-02   7     a
6   2014-01-03   4     a
7   2014-01-04   7     a
8   2014-01-05   9     b
9   2014-01-05  10     b
10  2014-01-05   5     b
11  2014-01-05   3     b
12  2014-01-06   2     b
13  2014-01-07   7     b
14  2014-01-07   3     b
15  2014-01-08   8     b
16  2014-01-09   4     c
17  2014-01-10   3     c
18  2014-01-10   7     c
19  2014-01-10   2     c
20  2014-01-10   5     c
21  2014-01-11   5     c
22  2014-01-12   2     c
23  2014-01-12   2     c
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define your level masks and set the level column value, I've converted the 'date' column to a datetime dtype for ease of comparison:

```
In [61]:
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
a_mask = (df1['date']>='2014-01-01') & (df1['date']<='2014-01-04')
b_mask = (df1['date']>='2014-01-05') & (df1['date']<='2014-01-08')
c_mask = (df1['date']>='2014-01-09') & (df1['date']<='2014-01-12')
df1.loc[a_mask, 'level'] = 'a'
df1.loc[b_mask, 'level'] = 'b'
df1.loc[c_mask, 'level'] = 'c'
df1

Out[61]:
         date  x1 level
0  2014-01-01   1     a
1  2014-01-01   5     a
2  2014-01-01   2     a
3  2014-01-01   6     a
4  2014-01-02   3     a
5  2014-01-02   7     a
6  2014-01-03   4     a
7  2014-01-04   7     a
8  2014-01-05   9     b
9  2014-01-05  10     b
10 2014-01-05   5     b
11 2014-01-05   3     b
12 2014-01-06   2     b
13 2014-01-07   7     b
14 2014-01-07   3     b
15 2014-01-08   8     b
16 2014-01-09   4     c
17 2014-01-10   3     c
18 2014-01-10   7     c
19 2014-01-10   2     c
20 2014-01-10   5     c
21 2014-01-11   5     c
22 2014-01-12   2     c
23 2014-01-12   2     c
```

Comment: I agree but couldn't think of a way that would play nice using pd.cut, your answer is better so I'll delete mine

Comment: I guess it depends on the number of levels for small number of levels this will be faster than calling apply but code wise it doesn't scale to increasing levels well

Comment: Guess you're right - depends on the number of dates.